# Under Ubuntu 17.10 an EPSON WF 2630 other than the test page it prints only Rubbish

Tags: drivers, 17.10, printing, epson

I installed Artful Aardvark an everything works just fine, even the scanner.
In connected the Printer via WI-Fi, used the reccomended drivers, and the test Page came out and everything looked fine. 
But when i wanted to print out something else a) the printer gave the "printing" status for a brief time, then doing nothing, or it printed pages full of data rubbish.

has anybody a clue of whats going on?

thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1026486/edit) your original question **above** and add more details of the problem. What program are you using to print? Are you trying to print a web page, a document, a picture, or a movie? Can you print plain text files from `gedit`?

Answer (score 1):

The driver that Epson would recommend for this printer; came out on **2nd April 2018**.

Get it from here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=71623&DSCCHK=e1fdb812f3b09b3da605fd49ef90a9e43b62db49

Assuming one has 64bit Ubuntu, get **epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.20-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb**

as a deb package, select OPEN when you begin the download; and gdebi installer should do the install. If one SAVES it to the Downloads folder, then locate it there and double-click to do the install;

best before doing this to go to the PRINTERS folder; delete any WF-2630 icon (as you say it is not working)